# unable to install B2B extension for magento 2.2.0

Tags: magento2.2, b2b

I m using magento 2.2.0 and trying to install B2B extension via composer require

`composer require magento/extension-b2b`

but i am getting bellow error

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package magento/extension-b2b at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package
  spelling or your minimum-stability
```

I m using link for installation:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/comp-mgr/install-extensions/b2b-installation.html

Comment: are you using community edition?

Comment: yes i m using magento ce 2.2.0

Comment: By default Magento CE with B2B functionality is not available, Its only for Magento EE