# Unable to install Magento B2B extension for Magento 2.2.0 Community Edition

Tags: magento2, extensions, magento2.2, cli, magento-community

[image]

I am working with Magento community edition 2.2.0. It gave this error when I executed `composer require magento/extension-b2b`

Comment: it seems there is typo, composer require magento/extensi on-b2b -vvv ?

Comment: it's impossible, i tried it more than 30 times,i tried change version 2.2.0 - 2.2.5-dev and execute this command but it still thrown this error

Comment: Review this : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/comp-mgr/install-extensions/b2b-installation.html

Comment: there are some issue like this , but not got any answers:- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/214566/could-not-install-b2b-extension-for-magento-2-2-0-ee?s=1|93.2979 - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196419/unable-to-install-b2b-extension-for-magento-2-2-0?s=2|89.9348

Comment: You use Magento Open Source 2.2. Right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not available for CE edition. Its only available in commerce only EE.

Please review this : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/comp-mgr/install-extensions/b2b-installation.html

[image]

Comment: thank you . by the way , how to get ee if i'm only a developer ?

Comment: Please review : https://www.demacmedia.com/magento-ee-install/